# Stepper motor shaft vibrates, and vibrates the load

Tags: pic, stepper-motor, driver, stepper-driver

I am new to the electronics hobby so any help is appreciated. For my application I need a quiet motor that can provide high torque at low speed.

I purchased a NEMA 17 stepper motor (model is 17HS4401s) and I am using the [DRV8825](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf) driver chip and a PIC microcontroller to drive it. I've connected the circuit as in the diagram below with a 12 V, 2 A motor power supply.

[image]

Now, after getting the motor to work, mounting it using screws, and attaching the load, the motor itself is stable, but the shaft vibrates and causes the load to vibrate with it. I've tried the following:

1. Microstepping the motor to 1/32 steps -> Reduced the vibrations a lot but the load still vibrates
2. Limiting the current to 1.4 A -> Did not make a difference
3. Limiting the current to 1 A -> Again reduced the vibration a bit but the load still vibrates
4. Different step frequency values (0.5 ms, 1 ms and 2 ms) but no significant change happened

Is there a way to get a smooth stable motion from the motor and stop the shaft from vibrating? Would switching to a different driver like the [TMC2100](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2100_datasheet_Rev1.11.pdf) SilentStepStick make a difference?

Comment: What is the motor part number (or if you don't have it, how many degrees per step), and how fast is the shaft rotating when it is vibrating objectionably?

Comment: The motor is 200 steps (1.8 degree) stepper with 1/32 microstepping so so 6400 steps per rotation. and I send a new step signal every 0.5 ms

Comment: Can you post a picture of the mechanical setup?  My stepper vibrates when not mounted solidly.

Comment: if you have a scope and a cheap current sense transformer, stick it on one of the motor wires, you can learn a lot. there are many potential reasons

Comment: one clue to look for: remove load, and/or damp shaft with finger, see if it gets better. another thing to try that can be a clue: temporarily plug in a larger stiffer power supply. another one:  try a different driver with same mech. setup. another: motor gets extremely hot.

Comment: the 100uF bypass should be very stiff too, IMO. But hopefully that little pcb took care of that. Finally, I don't know this driver, but mistuned drivers will result in this symptom

Comment: @PeteW Thanks alot for the suggestions. I don't have a scope unfortunately, I tried dampening the shaft with my finger and hand and still vibrates even when I pressure it. The motor does not get hot at all and I will try to get my hands on another driver to try it

Comment: @PeteW I do not understand the part about the 100 uF capacitor? can it cause problems?

Comment: @Mattman944 I removed the setup before taking pictures but I try to fix firmly with my hands. the body does not vibrate at all but the shaft does

Comment: @moaz re: 100uF probably not, Pololu knows how to make a decent driver board. my first guess is power supply V insufficient for your current level at your speed, second guess is current insufficient for load, third was inappropriate load vs resonance (try damping - you did that), final guess is power quality

Comment: try slower speeds. (keep the microstep). look at the motor torque curves carefully vs V and I from power. Remember you have two windings.

Comment: @PeteW Instead of PWM for step with 0.5 ms ON and 0.5 OFF, I tried 1 ms OFF and 0.5 ms ON, it did make a small difference 
Also regarding the load, my load is currently very light (less than 150 gram). Would a bigger load make a difference or absorb those vibrations ?

Comment: re: bigger load - hard to say.  re:speed - try 100rpm, that should be pretty smooth for a typical nema17 stepper even with limited voltage

Comment: Ultimately, stepper motors step. You can't get smooth motion from something that moves in discrete steps. Would you be better off with a geared conventional motor, with position feedback if your application needs it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Only use full steps for max torque. Use appropriate pulley ratios on belt to increase torque as required.
2. motor noise while moving  is due to mechanical resonance, which is dependent on lack of stiffness and lack of damping and bearing slop exciting frame resonance.
3. Motor noise while idle should not occur but if you hear a squeal noise , it is because of electrical resonance , which depends on supply noise and cable characteristics which transfers motor inductance to the  driver.
4. Ensure at if 2A=24W that the motor has a miniature fan for cooling and same for electronics.
5. Your motor coil specs are 1.7A and 1.5 Ohms.

Comment: I would think it is perfectly possible for torque variations to cause vibration. Stepper motors are not known for smooth torque. Do you think it is impossible that the vibration is caused by torque variations during rotation?

Comment: @Tony I don't mind the noise as much I mind the vibration. and I don't know the reason r the fix for that vibration

Comment: @mkeith I have considered that, but I found people on videos and the internet using stepper motor and never complaining about vibration so maybe it is something wrong with my config? 
I need to drive the load from the motor directly and avoid belts or gears or something similar

Comment: I was talking to Tony. He seems to be dismissing the idea that the steps are causing the vibration. I note you say that microstepping helped, so I wonder if torque pulses are causing vibration. In my experience, vibration usually IS caused by mechanical issues. But I would think that with a stepper motor it could also be caused by torque vibrations.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated it, and in some respects you contradict it, but I'll assume that

"the motor itself is stable, yet the shaft vibrates and causes the causing the load to vibrate with it."

refers to the motor shaft being stationary.

Since you don't have position or velocity feedback, the only likely source of vibration is the PWM frequency used to regulate the current level. This suggests that the driver is faulty, and the PWM frequency is too low, so you can actually see the shaft/load respond.

I'd recommend trying another driver.